# Base class A holds base class B property but derived class A1 holds derived class B1

Tags: c#, oop

I've got the following real-world pattern where a base class `BCA` holds a public property `B` of base class type `BCB`. Both `BCA` and `BCB` have two derived classes each - `DCA1` and `DCA2`, `DCB1` and `DCB2` respectively. In each of `DCA1` and `DCA2`, the property in the real-world is actually of type `DCB1` and `DCB2` respectively.

How is this most efficiently translated into code - OOP design? Do I keep `B` in `BCA`, or should I concrete type it in each of `DCA1` and `DCA2`? Should I use generics? Is there anything wrong with this design? It happens that I have come across it a couple of times already in this project, and somehow it doesn't feel right; but I am wondering if my conception is wrong.

**EDIT:**
I am giving a more concrete example to make it clearer. I am sorry but I am not allowed to post images to show it on a class diagram but this is how it goes:

A Pet has a DailyMeal property of type PetFood. The Cat's DailyMeal property is of type CatFood and the Dog's DailyMeal is of type DogFood.

I hope this makes the pattern clearer.

**EDIT2:**
The question is re-expressed as: How do you model such a real-world scenario where you have a Car with an Engine, an ElectricCar with an ElectricEngine and a DieselCar with a DieselEngine etc, in OOP terms and in particular in C#, so that you can use polymorphism:

`Car myCar = myElectricCar;`

```
myCar.Engine = myElectricEngine;
```

etc, and at the same time ensuring that each Car type will have the correct Engine type. The goal is to model this real-world scenario in terms of Classes, Interfaces and/or Generics or whatever it takes and reap the full benefits of OOP.

Comment: If those properties are writable, then this violates Liskov's substitution principle. In any case, there is no good solution with classes, but you can use covariant interfaces.

Comment: All your acronyms are really confusing. Is there any chance you could show some sample code with simpler names?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior A Car has an Engine. An ElectricCar has an ElectricEngine.

Comment: put your code sample and output

Comment: @Kris Vandermotten - Covariance and Contravariance looks like the way to go. I had come across these in a quick read in the past but had completely forgotten their existence. Plus, only now I see their relevance! Concerning Liskov's substitution principle, I was only modelling the "real-world" situation. This was not the actual implementation I had chosen. If you make this into an answer it could be chosen as the solution. Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: First of all, classes cannot be covariant, only interfaces can. You can design this as covariant interfaces only if the property is read-only. I'll turn this into an answer.

Comment: I have made a 2nd edit to the question to make the objective clearer. I don't see a way to change the title. If possible I would like to change it to "How to model in C# OOP terms the pattern where Base class A holds Base Class B property, Derived class A1 holds Derived class B1 etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the following example: all cars have engines, but electric cars have electric engines.

You cannot design this with classes, but you can with covariant interfaces:

```
interface ICar<out TEngine>
{
    TEngine Engine { get; }
}

class Engine { }

class Car : ICar<Engine>
{
    private readonly Engine engine;

    public Car(Engine engine)
    {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public Engine Engine { get { return this.engine; } }
}

class ElectricEngine : Engine { }

class ElectricCar : ICar<ElectricEngine>
{
    private readonly ElectricEngine engine;

    public Car(ElectricEngine engine)
    {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public ElectricEngine Engine { get { return this.engine; } }
}
```

Notice however that ElectricCar does not inherit from Car. However, `ICar<ElectricEngine>` is assignable to `ICar<Engine>`, so this works:

```
ICar<Engine> myCar = new ElectricCar(new ElectricEngine());
```

Of course, you could also define a non-generic interface ICar, that holds all properties and methods that have nothing to do with the engine.

Notice that `ICar<out TEngine>` is covariant. It cannot be also contravariant. What that means is that the Engine property must be read-only.

**UPDATE**

You asked why the property must be read-only, and whether there would be something inherently wrong with it being writable. Well yes there would. Consider this scenario:

```
ICar<Engine> myCar = new ElectricCar();

// assume ICar<Engine> has a writabel property Engine of type Engine

myCar.Engine = new DieselEngine();
```

A writable property of type Engine would have to allow that last statement. But at runtime this cannot work of course, because myCar happens to be an ElectricCar, and those don't take DieselEngines.

I suggest you read about the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

It would be OK for `ElectricCar` to have a writable `Engine` property of type `ElectricEngine`, its setter just can't be part of the `ICar<TEngine>` interface. Because of that, the setter of the property cannot be polymorphic.

Comment: Very interesting! Can we work around the readonly constraint or is there something inherently wrong with needing this? 
The problem is now re-expressed as:
"We have two sets of hierarchies (Cars and Engines) that are coupled together in the hierarchy chain (ElectriCars-ElectricEngines, DieselCars-DieselEngines etc.)
We need to establish this coupling, be able to use polymorphism and be able to change the coupled property (Car's Engine) during the lifetime of the objects."
Can this be done (in C#)?

Comment: Had a quick look at Liskov Substitution Principle. Looks quite involved and will look more carefully in it. However, in your solution I fully understand why it is impossible to have a writable property. The question was whether it is possible to achieve this in any way in C# (i.e. this type of hierarchy coupling, polymorphism and writable property). From the Liskov Substitution Principle I get the feeling that it might be theoretically impossible. Is that right?

Comment: @GDS It is a bad idea, and it is not possible in .NET. In theory, one could create a system in which it is possible, and rely on runtime exceptions to detect illegal use. That is what would have to be done in dynamic languages. Unfortunately, it also exists in .NET for arrays: you can assign a `ElectricEngine[]` to a variable of type `Engine[]`, and then write to an element in the array. If it turns out to be of the wrong type at runtime, you'll get an exception. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use generics. Make BCA generic in its property type, and constrain it to a be derived from BCB:

```
class BCA<T> where T: BCB
{
    public T prop {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that we do not couple the two sets of hierarchies together (see comment on Kris Vandermotten's answer). With simple use of generics we can get a DieselCar with an ElectricEngine.